# Difference between await and Task.Wait

Tags: c#

First way:

```
var tds=SearchProcess();
await tds;

public async  Task<XmlElement> SearchProcess()
{
}
```

Second way:

```
var tds= Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>SearchProcess());
Task.WaitAll(tds);

public XmlElement SearchProcess()
{
}
```

In above both approach any performance difference is there?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519414/whats-the-difference-between-task-start-wait-and-async-await

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140523/await-vs-task-wait-deadlock?rq=1

Answer (score 8):

`Task.WaitAll` is blocking, while using `await` will make the containing method `async`. To wait for multiple tasks asynchronously you can use `Task.WhenAll`:

```
public async Task DoSomething()
{
    IEnumerable<Task> tds = SearchProcess();
    await Task.WhenAll(tds);
    //continue processing    
}
```