# Task is not waiting for completion

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm trying to get my head around await and async so I wrote this little test app, but what I expected does not happen.

Instead of waiting for the task to complete, the program continues to execute.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var task = new Task(Run);
        task.Start();
        task.Wait();

        Console.WriteLine("Main finished");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public async static void Run()
    {
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("End");
        });

        await task;
        Console.WriteLine("Run finished");
    }
}
```

Output

```
Main finished
Starting
End
Run finished
```

If I swap the 'await task' for 'task.Await()' it then runs as I would have expected producing

```
Starting
End
Run finished
Main finished
```

Comment: I hope this link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/9519578/2798643

Comment: I have an [async intro blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) that you may find useful. Note that your code [should not use the task constructor](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html) [nor `Task.Factory.StartNew`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html) (both links to my blog).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because when you have asynchronous `void` method, there is nothing you can do to track it's completion. Yours `new Task(Run)` only creates a task for starting the Run method. After the Run arrives at first await, there is nothing tracking the progress of the method, because there is nothing associated with the progress of the method. To fix it, you have to return `Task` instead of `void` and await that, instead of creating new Task.

Difference between `async void` and `async Task` is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).