# Async with only one await

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, parallel-processing

Does this code make sense?

```
async Task DoSomething() {
     await service.doSomething();
}
```

Is it just similar in this?

```
Task DoSomething() {
    return service.doSomething();
}
```

OR is it just the same to this?

```
 void DoSomething() {
    service.doSomething().Wait();
}
```

Which code is the best on this scenario?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519414/whats-the-difference-between-task-start-wait-and-async-await

Comment: On *which* scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your initial example:

```
async Task DoSomething() 
{
     await service.doSomething();
}
```

Is a slightly more inefficient version than your first alternative:

```
Task DoSomething() 
{
    return service.doSomething();
}
```

It's more expensive because it has to create the whole state machine related to async code whereas the version shown above does not require that.  If you were to use a disassembler such as IlSpy and inspect the compiler generated symbols, you'd see that a special class gets created for your `async` version (`DoSomething<d__0>` or some such) that would not be created if you did not use async.

On the other hand, your second example -- using `.Wait()` -- should be avoided whenever possible.  It illustrates two problems:

- Using `.Wait` means you're opting-out of `async`, which defeats the whole point. (The "async" code now gets invoked on the calling thread and blocks)
- Using `.Wait` also often leads to thread deadlocks that are best solved by allowing `await` semantics to propagate through your code.

Comment: But the first example is not necessarily wrong right? it is just ineficient?

Comment: Correct.  It is only somewhat inefficient.  In most scenarios you should probably ignore performance implications here and go for what you think is most readable.

Comment: I think it's also appropriate to point out the fact that when `SynchronizationContext.Current` is not `null`, the first code snippet (with `await` but no `ConfigureAwait(false)`) introduces the possibility of a deadlock (if the caller blocks on the returned `Task`'s completion) where there was potentially none before. That alone is a good enough reason to stay away from `async/await` where it otherwise adds no value.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy, I never thought of that.  That's a great point.