# What causes the glitch when passing loop counter to Task-based method below?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

- `static Task<int> GetPrimeCountAsync(int start, int stop)` is for counting the number of primes in a closed interval `[start,stop]` where `2 < start <= stop`.
- `static void WrapperAsync()` is for printing a list of 10 executions of `GetPrimeCountAsync`, each with a closed interval spanning from `i == 0 ? 3 : 1000_000 * i` to `1000_000 * (i + 1) - 1`, where `i` spinning from `0` to `9`.
  Inside this method, there are 3 cases, only one is activated.

  1. when case 1 is activated, the result is as follows:

     [image]
  2. when case 2 is activated, the result is as follows:

     [image]
  3. when case 3 is activated, the result is as follows:

     [image]

## Questions

If we compare case 1, 2 and 3, there are the same glitches in case 1 and 2 but not in case 3. The case 3 is the wanted result.

Actually the glitches can be removed by buffering the loop counter with local variables as follows:

```
int start = i == 0 ? 3 : 1000_000 * i;
int stop = 1000_000 * (i + 1) - 1;
```

And then just pass `start` and `stop` to `GetPrimeCountAsync` and `WriteLine`.

The question is: What causes these 2 glitches in case 1 and 2?

## Complete Code

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using static System.Console;


class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        WrapperAsync();
        WriteLine("Ended...");
    }


    static void WrapperAsync()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            //int start = i == 0 ? 3 : 1000_000 * i;
            //int stop = 1000_000 * (i + 1) - 1;

            // case 1: OnCompleted
            var awaiter = GetPrimeCountAsync(i == 0 ? 3 : 1000_000 * i, 1000_000 * (i + 1) - 1).GetAwaiter();
            awaiter.OnCompleted(() => WriteLine($"The number of primes between {(i == 0 ? 3 : 1000_000 * i)} and {1000_000 * (i + 1) - 1} is {awaiter.GetResult()}"));

            // case 2: ContinueWith
            //var task = GetPrimeCountAsync(i == 0 ? 3 : 1000_000 * i, (i + 1) * 1000_000 - 1);
            //task.ContinueWith(t => WriteLine($"The number of primes between {(i == 0 ? 3 : 1000_000 * i)} and {(i + 1) * 1000_000 - 1} is {t.GetAwaiter().GetResult()}"));

            // case 3: without OnCompleted and without ContinueWith
            //var task = GetPrimeCountAsync(i == 0 ? 3 : 1000_000 * i, (i + 1) * 1000_000 - 1);
            //WriteLine($"The number of primes between {(i == 0 ? 3 : 1000_000 * i)} and {(i + 1) * 1000_000 - 1} is {task.GetAwaiter().GetResult()}");
        }
    }

    //  Note that 2 < start <= stop 
    static Task<int> GetPrimeCountAsync(int start, int stop)
    {
        var count = ParallelEnumerable.Range(start, stop - start + 1)
                    .Where(i => i % 2 > 0)
                    .Count(j => Enumerable.Range(3, (int)Math.Sqrt(j) - 1).Where(k => k % 2 > 0).All(l => j % l > 0));

        return Task.Run(() => count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "glitches" you described come from the fact that the for loop uses one variable. In `awaiter.OnCompleted(() => WriteLine($"The number of primes between {(i == 0 ? 3 : 1000_000 * i)} and {1000_000 * (i + 1) - 1} is {awaiter.GetResult()}"));`
 the lambda you pass to `OnCompleted` is a closure over `i` in the `for` loop. It means that it uses the current value of `i` and not the one from the time you passed it to the function. You can see that behaviour when you do

```
List<Action> actions = new List<Action>();
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    actions.Add(()=>Console.WriteLine(i + 1))

foreach(Action a in actions) 
    a();
```

It prints `10` 10 times. To make it print numbers from 1 to 10 you'd have to do

```
List<Action> actions = new List<Action>();
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    int temp = i;
    actions.Add(()=>Console.WriteLine(temp + 1))
} 

foreach(Action a in actions) 
    a();
```

[This Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/428617/)
talks about closures in more detail.

This is the reason why if you use

```
int start = i == 0 ? 3 : 1000_000 * i;
int stop = 1000_000 * (i + 1) - 1;
```

you get what you wanted. Without it the task takes more time than one iteration of the loop, so it uses the next value of i.

---

There's actually something else you should do differently. Async methods should use the `async` keyword, so your signatures should look like

```
static async Task<int> GetPrimeCountAsync(int start, int stop)
```

and

```
static async Task WrapperAsync() //notice the Task return type
```

You shouldn't use `GetAwaiter`, use `await` instead. You can read about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/await).
So instead of

```
return Task.Run(() => count);
```

you can now write

```
return count;
```

Leave the harder stuff for the compiler.

If you want to have it all done asynchronously you should use only the second option with a little change:

```
var task = GetPrimeCountAsync(start, stop)
    .ContinueWith(t => WriteLine($"The number of primes between {start} and {stop} is {t.Result}"));
```

If you want them to execute in order you can write

```
await GetPrimeCountAsync(start, stop)
    .ContinueWith(t => WriteLine($"The number of primes between {start} and {stop} is {t.Result}"));
```

in the loop instead. Other than that, If you want to print everything before `Ended...` you can write

```
await WrapperAsync(); //in c# 7
//or
WrapperAsync().Wait();
```

in `Main`. Actually I think you have to do it, because the application can terminate when it reaches the end of `Main` without waiting for all the tasks to complete. If you don't require  `Ended...` to be written after all the tasks you can do

```
var wrapperTask = WrapperAsync();
WriteLine("Ended...");
await wrapperTask;
//or wrapperTask.Wait();
```

**Complete code should look more or less like this**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using static System.Console;


class Program
{
    //since c# 7
    static async Task Main()
    {
        //use this or other options I provided
        await WrapperAsync();
        WriteLine("Ended...");
    }

    //earlier versions of c#
    static void Main() 
    {
        WrapperAsync().Wait();
        WriteLine("Ended...");
    }


    static async Task WrapperAsync()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            int start = i == 0 ? 3 : 1000_000 * i;
            int stop = 1000_000 * (i + 1) - 1;

            //you can also change it here to do exactly what you want
            await GetPrimeCountAsync(start, stop)
                .ContinueWith(t => WriteLine($"The number of primes between {start} and {stop} is {t.Result}"));
        }
    }

    //  Note that 2 < start <= stop 
    static async Task<int> GetPrimeCountAsync(int start, int stop)
    {
        var count = ParallelEnumerable.Range(start, stop - start + 1)
                    .Where(i => i % 2 > 0)
                    .Count(j => Enumerable.Range(3, (int)Math.Sqrt(j) - 1).Where(k => k % 2 > 0).All(l => j % l > 0));

        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can `await` inside `Main`?

Comment: Actually since c#7 you can specify the Main to be async. For earlier versions you have to do it synchronously. I will update the answer

Comment: I read that you can use Wait() instead, but there's a difference between await and Wait(). Read this https://stackoverflow.com/q/9519414/ for some more info.

Comment: I'm still somewhat new to the whole multithreading thing so not everything may behave as expected. You should read up on that elsewhere and so should I.