# Calling await on the task directly. C#

Tags: c#, async-await

I am learning await/async right now. and I have a question: 
Is there a difference between calling the await directly on the task and call it later?

```
var task = getAllAsync();
...
var list = await task;
```

OR

```
var list = await getAllAsync();
```

If there is a difference, what is it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519414/whats-the-difference-between-task-start-wait-and-async-await

Comment: There is no real practical difference... you just introduced an intermediate variable in one case...

Comment: There's only a difference if there's code between the assignment and the `await`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you await immediately after assigning "task" to a variable there is no difference. If you have code between method call and await-ing you have chance to execute operations in parallel.

Most tasks are created "hot" - they already have started operation (like reading file). As result if you have some code before `await` that code may execute while operation started by task is going on separately. I.e. you can start multiple tasks and than wait for all of them to complete - [Running multiple async tasks and waiting for them all to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009437/running-multiple-async-tasks-and-waiting-for-them-all-to-complete).