# Why does this Task return early? Have I done something wrong?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I'm trying to set up a bunch of workers with some minimal coupling, but I'd like to use C# `async` and tasks. Not all of the tasks will be purely asynchronous (some will be completely synchronous). The motivation for doing this is that I want to create some simple methods that execute business logic, and chain them together using the `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` API to preserve some notion of ordering. Basically, I want to create a first task, register some continuations, and then wait for the final task to complete.

Here's the simple prototype I built just to see if what I want to do even works:

```
void Main()
{
    var worker = new Worker();

    var work = worker.StartWork(1, 2000);
    work.ConfigureAwait(false);

    var final = work.ContinueWith(_ => worker.StartWork(2, 0))
        .ContinueWith(ant => worker.StartWork(3, 1500));

    var awaiter = final.ContinueWith(_ => Tuple.Create(_.Id, _.Status));
    Console.WriteLine("\"final\" completed with result {0}", awaiter.Result);
    Console.WriteLine("Done.");
}

// Define other methods and classes here
class Worker {
    internal async Task StartWork(int phase, int delay) {
        Console.WriteLine("Entering phase {0} (in Task {1}) with {2} milliseconds timeout.", phase, Task.CurrentId, delay);
        if (delay > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Do wait for {0} milliseconds.", delay);
            await Task.Delay(delay);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("ending phase {0}", phase);
    }
}
```

The problem seems to be in <del>awaiting</del> waiting on the so-called `awaiter` task:

```
Entering phase 1 (in Task ) with 2000 milliseconds timeout.
Do wait for 2000 milliseconds.
ending phase 1
Entering phase 2 (in Task 769) with 0 milliseconds timeout.
ending phase 2
Entering phase 3 (in Task 770) with 1500 milliseconds timeout.
Do wait for 1500 milliseconds.
"final" completed with result (770, RanToCompletion)
Done.
ending phase 3
```

Is this just not supported? I thought I understood the `Task` API pretty well, but clearly I don't. I think that I can convert this to not use `async` or task, and just execute the method completely synchronously, but that seems like a bad method of doing things. The continuations that I want to run are not exactly this (they just accept a `CancellationToken`). There's no particular dependency on messages between tasks - I just need to preserve some notion of ordering.

Thank you.

**Edit:** I incorrectly used the word `awaiting` above: I know that accessing `Task.Result` is completely synchronous. My apologies.

**Edit 2:** What I expected to occur was that calling `ContinueWith(_ => worker.Start(2, 0))` would return a task to `ContinueWith`, and the TPL would internally await the task returned by `worker.StartWork` when my user delegate returned a task. Looking at the overload list for `ContinueWith`, this was clearly incorrect. Part of what I'm trying to solve is how to wait from the `Main` method that schedules the work; I don't want to exit before all continuations have completed.

The motivation I had for using `ContinueWith` was that I have requirements similar to the following:

1. There are three phases to the main method.
2. Phase 1 creates three workers: `a`, `b`, and `c`.
3. Phase 2 starts an additional worker `d` upon the completion of tasks `b` and `c`, and another worker `e` upon completion of `a` and `b` (the dependency is that these tasks must be created in this order)
4. A process similar to this follows until all the work is complete.

If I understand the feedback in the comments correctly, I have essentially two ways I can do this:

1. Make the methods synchronous, and register the continuations myself.
2. Leave the methods marked as `async Task`, and use the `await` keyword along with the `Task.WhenAll` API to schedule the continuations.

Comment: I think the reason, reviewing the docs, is because I am not passing `TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent`, so the `Task` continuation is being created in the detached state. Is there anyone out there that's more familiar able to confirm this by chance?

Comment: I am confused as to why you would think anything else would happen. You've created an asynchronous workflow where most of the tasks are not awaited; as I keep on saying on SO: **await is the sequencing operation on an asynchronous workflow**.  You have put in hardly any sequencing, and so it should be expected that not everything runs sequentially, right?

Comment: Say more clearly what you expected to happen here and why you expected it, and someone can explain to you where you've gone wrong in your thinking.

Comment: You need to `await` your tasks.  Also `ContinueWith` is old school now that we have `await`

Comment: @EricLippert, my apologies; I thought the question was clear. I've updated the question to try to clarify. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: @MickyD, do you mean simply replacing the calls to `ContinueWith` with simple `awaits`, and leaving it to the compiler to figure out continuations? I believe I've clearly outlined (in edit 2) why I wanted to use `ContinueWith`. I could likely break this up into more method, but my hope was to keep the continuation scheduling (even if it's using `await`) all in one highly localized spot in my codebase. In any case, thank you for the feedback.

Comment: Well no, like I said, there is zero reason to use `ContinueWith` in this day and age

Comment: @MickyD Well actually there is, like if you want to use a different task scheduler for a continuation, or if you want it to run inline. But yeah, async/await covers all common cases

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Kevin's answer is good. But based on the comments you seem to have the belief that "continuewith" somehow gives you more power than await when describing the sequencing of a workflow. It does not. Also, the question of how to structure your workflow of your second edit properly without resorting to explicit continuations has not been addressed.

Let's look at your scenario. Your workflow is: we have tasks A, B, C, D and E. Starting D depends on the completion of B and C; starting E depends on the completion of A and B.

Easily done. Remember: **await is the sequencing operation on tasks**.  Any time we wish to say "Y must come after X", we simply put an await X *anywhere before Y is started*. Conversely, if we do not wish a task to be forced to complete before something, we don't await it.

Here's a tiny little framework to play with; this probably isn't how I would write your real code, but it clearly illustrates the workflow.

```
    private async Task DoItAsync(string s, int d)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"starting {s}");
        await Task.Delay(d * 1000);
        Console.WriteLine($"ending {s}");
    }

    private async Task DoItAsync(Task pre1, Task pre2, string s, int d)
    {
        await pre1;
        await pre2;
        await DoItAsync(s, d);
    }

    private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task atask = DoItAsync("A", 2);
        Task btask = DoItAsync("B", 10);
        Task ctask = DoItAsync("C", 2);
        Task bcdtask = DoItAsync(btask, ctask, "D", 2);
        Task abetask = DoItAsync(btask, atask, "E", 2);
        await bcdtask;
        await abetask;
    }
```

Follow along.  A, B and C are started.  (Remember, THEY ARE ALREADY ASYNCHRONOUS.  "await" does not make them asynchronous; await introduces a sequencing point in a workflow.)

Next our two helper tasks are started. The preconditions of D are B and C, so we await B. Let's suppose B is incomplete, so the await returns a task to the caller, representing the workflow of "start d after b and c are done, and wait for d to complete".

Now we start our second helper task. Again, it awaits B. Let's again suppose it is incomplete. We return to the caller.

Now we add the final bit of structure to our workflow. **The workflow is not complete until the two helper tasks are complete**. The two helper tasks are not complete until D and E are complete, and they will not even start until B and C, in the case of D, or B and A, in the case of E, are completed.

Use this little framework to play around with the timings of when stuff completes and you will see that it is very straightforward to build up dependencies in the workflow by using `await`. **That's what it is for**. It's called await because it *asynchronously waits for a task to complete*.

Comment: Thanks for posting this Eric. I've marked this as the answer due to the sequencing aspect - which is the problem I'm really trying to solve.

Comment: @PSGuy: Quite fine. Notice that I'm using windows forms here as the foundation of my little test app because I find it easier to reason about asynchrony in an environment that has a message loop and an apartment threading model.  I try to avoid console apps when trying out ideas for asynchrony.

Answer (score 2):

> What I expected to occur was that calling ContinueWith(_ => worker.Start(2, 0)) would return a task to ContinueWith, and the TPL would internally await the task returned by worker.StartWork when my user delegate returned a task. Looking at the overload list for ContinueWith, this was clearly incorrect.

That's indeed what you missed. In your case `.ContinueWith` will return a `Task<Task>` and not just a `Task` like you expected. That said, this can be easily fixed by using the `Unwrap` method to convert the nested tasks into a single one:

```
var worker = new Worker();

var work = worker.StartWork(1, 2000);

var final = work.ContinueWith(_ => worker.StartWork(2, 0)).Unwrap()
    .ContinueWith(ant => worker.StartWork(3, 1500)).Unwrap();

var awaiter = final.ContinueWith(_ => Tuple.Create(_.Id, _.Status));
Console.WriteLine("\"final\" completed with result {0}", awaiter.Result);
Console.WriteLine("Done.");
```

This will give you the desired output. But as other have mentioned, you may want to use async/await instead, as it'll make your code much easier to read and follow (and will protect you from some corner cases of `ContinueWith`) :

```
static async Task DoWork()
{
    var worker = new Worker();

    await worker.StartWork(1, 2000);
    await worker.StartWork(2, 0);
    await worker.StartWork(3, 1500);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DoWork().Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("Done.");
}
```